# Maven changes the order of plugins of different profiles

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have a `pom.xml` where I define the same `plugin` (same `groupId` and `artifactId`, different `execution` :-) ) in two different `profiles`. The `executions` are defined in the same `phase`, so the order is calculated by the order from the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>echo</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <name>echo-test</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>1st-profile</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>1st-antrun-echo</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <echo>1st antrun plugin</echo>
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>2nd-profile</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>1st-soebes-echo</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>echo</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <echos>
                                        <echo>1st echo-plugin</echo>
                                    </echos>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>2nd-antrun-echo</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <tasks>
                                        <echo>2nd antrun plugin</echo>
                                    </tasks>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

All the plugin executions are defined in the `test` phase, therefore I would expect the following order:

```
1st antrun plugin
1st echo-plugin
2nd antrun plugin
```

However, since the `antrun-plugins` are merged, I get this output:

```
1st echo-plugin    
1st antrun plugin    
2nd antrun plugin
```

This command explains why is this happening: `mvn help:effective-pom`

Is there any other solution to preserve the order other than to introduce a new phases? Our project is really big and this is a very simplified example.

Why is this limitation of maven to merge the plugins into one with multiple executions?

Comment: Do you really need those profiles?

Comment: Yes, in my project I do need those profiles. The example is a very simplified projection of a project I am dealing with.

Comment: You could submit your pom as example for the MNG-2258 bug below.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In my experience this is one of the biggest bugs in Maven. If you have more than one configuration for the same plugin in different profiles, the order is simply unpredictable. I even observed, that I had some plugin order in project B in a given phase, and as soon as some of the same plugins got a config in a parent project (not even in the same phase), the order was ruined.

There is an obviously falsely closed bug related to this at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-2258.

### Possible workarounds

- Try to shift some of the plugins to previous phase if possible
  (prepare-test used for some of the plugins and test for the rest)
- Try
  to replace the functionality of multiple plugins with a
  groovy-maven-plugin script (quite handy with the ant integration, and
  you reach the list of the active profiles in the script)
- Write your
  own mojo and call the plugins in the correct order (See
  https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor)
- Give a try to gradle. Maybe it fits your needs, and it comes with a lot of good things from Maven

I do not think that there is any more you can do right now.

Comment: from what I read in the linked bug, is seems like the order of plugins in pom is not decisive. I'm still not sure what is, but I found an open bug for documenting that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5987 - please vote, anyone who has got problem with that